# Marshmallow schema: allow any extra field as long as its name matches a pattern

Tags: python, validation, schema, marshmallow

I am building an API endpoint, and using Marshmallow for input validation and marshaling. One of the objects I want to accept has some specific fields, but will also accept additional fields as long as the field name begins with `x-`. So for example:

```
{
  "name": "Bob Paulson",  // a strict, required field
  "email": "bob@example.com",  // a strict, required field
  "x-dob": "1980-10-11" // not a part of the explicit schema but accepted because it begins with 'x-'
}
```

Is there a way to specify this in Marshmallow?

Comment: See https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#raising-errors-in-pre-post-processor-methods, does this look like the right direction? you could iterate over the keys in `data`, and reject keys that are not in the pattern you want. You can also add some serialization to the data there and return different input/outputs to the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `@pre_load` to put these fields on an `extras` field (for example), which may contain any data you want, see the Marshmallow docs about [Extending Schema](https://repl.it/@chenasraf/marshmallow-arbitrary-fields).

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, ValidationError, pre_load


class PersonSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Str()
    extra = fields.Dict()

    @pre_load
    def unwrap_envelope(self, data, **kwargs):
        extra = {}
        rest = {}
        for k, v in data.items():
          if k.startswith('x-'):
            extra[k] = v
          else:
            rest[k] = v
        return {'extra':extra,**rest}


sch = PersonSchema()
person_data = {"name": "John Doe", "email": "jdoe@email.com"}

try:
  res1 = sch.load({**person_data,"dob": "1980-11-11"})
  print(res1)
except ValidationError as err:
  print(err.messages)

try:
  res2 = sch.load({**person_data,"x-dob": "1980-11-11"})
  print(res2)
except ValidationError as err:
  print(err.messages)
```

The above should fail on the first print, and succeed on the second. [See a demo here](https://repl.it/@chenasraf/marshmallow-arbitrary-fields).